# Extract a part of scene as texture in THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

I would like to render a texture of a rectangular part of my scene like the example in three.js framebuffer [official documentation](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=frame#webgl_framebuffer_texture).
I look at the code and there is something thing I do not understand,

```
// calculate start position for copying data

            vector.x = ( window.innerWidth * dpr / 2 ) - ( textureSize / 2 );
            vector.y = ( window.innerHeight * dpr / 2 ) - ( textureSize / 2 );

            renderer.copyFramebufferToTexture( vector, texture );
```

The first parameter of copyFrameBufferToTexture is a Vector2 which is the starting position to copy the data.

What does this formulas mean?

Is it a world position or screen position?

My purpose is to insert a div element into the DOM then I will get all pixels data which are inside my div element.

Comment: I think it's better if you post your solution as an answer and not as a part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

By looking at the source code of copyFramebufferToTexture, I saw that it uses copyTexImage2D where (x,y) is the lower left (0,0) of your window.

So to answer to my question, the formula above is the coordinates window which start at the bottom left.

Then if anyone want to extract a part of scene by delimiting with div element, I have used this formulas:

```
vector.x = divElement.offsetLeft;
vector.y = webglRenderer.getSize().height - divElement.offsetTop - textureHeight;
```